# How to configure Selenium Webdriver with netbeans?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2

I installed netbeans and then Selenium Client Driver and the step i have done after installing Client Driver:

1. Open NetBeans IDE.
2. Goto File->New Project->Categories Java and Projects Java Application and click next.
3. Give the Project Name and Destination where it it will be saved and click finished.
4. Right Click on project which is shown on the left side of NetBeans and select Properties
   5.Add all jars with in the selenium-2.37.0 folder (selenium-2.37.0 + selenium-java-2.37.0-srcs.jar +All jar in libs folder)

After Completing this much steps also I couldn't start working on it..can anyone please tell if any other process I need to do after this, also please tell me how to start writing codes, because  Iam new to webdriver

Comment: you should use at least selenium 2.44 jar instead of old version.

Comment: you should also share code you have written as your first test.

Comment: Check this steps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974570/getting-started-with-netbeans-and-selenium

Comment: "I couldn't start working on it.." , what prevented you from starting working? You get errors or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of downloading and using your own Selenium jars I would use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/).
Maven is used as a build tool and will download any dependencies you might need, like the latest version of Selenium.

Steps:

1. Download & Install Netbeans with JDK at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html (Also install JUnit with the installer)
2. Install Firefox
3. Create a new project: Maven -> Java Application
4. Under project files edit pom.xml and add Selenium dependency

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.45.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

4. Right click project-name to get a menu and select: New -> Other. Pick the JUnit Test from the Unit Tests category. Next -> Finish.
5. Pasted the following code to replace the JUnit test file

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class NewEmptyJUnitTest {

  @Test
  public void hello() {
    WebDriver driver  = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13213/how-to-configure-selenium-webdriver-with-netbeans");
      WebElement acceptAnswerLink = driver.findElement(By.id("vote-accepted-13214"));
      acceptAnswerLink.click();  
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

6. Hit Ctrl-F6 to run the unit-tests

The result should be that Firefox starts opening this page and accepting this answer ;-)

Put the files on github: https://github.com/nreijmersdal/NetbeansMavenSelenium

Comment: Thanks for your reply  ,But while  doing 2nd step these much errors coming

Comment: Failed to execute goal on project application: Could not resolve dependencies for project demo.crud.mvn:application:nbm-application:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: demo.crud.mvn:crudsample:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT, demo.crud.mvn:branding:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact demo.crud.mvn:crudsample:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in netbeans (http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Comment: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Comment: @ Niels van Reijmersdal can you please check the above problem

Comment: I dont have netbeans installed, I dont think I will have time soon to verify it my self.

Comment: @ Niels van Reijmersdal  can you please suggest any alternative for using   Selenium WebDriver

Comment: When I was still writing Selenium tests in Java I was using Netbeans. I actually liked it pretty good. I have tried and updated my steps, seems you need the version. This should work, works on my Windows 7 machine :)

Comment: +1 , Do you know how to open the latest Firefox version, this works only for old version. Firefox opens , but it doesn't go to the expected link.

Comment: @AVI This example uses the 2.x Selenium version, I guess the new version of Firefox only works with the 3.x versions. If you are already using newer versions of Selenium I would ask a new question and add your current code in the question.